# Why am I getting a deprecated warning when using this xpath syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, chrome-web-driver

I am using selenium to print all of the product links on a webpage. Here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver_path = PATH = r"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Selenium\chromedriver.exe"

driver = Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)

driver.get('https://www.lazada.com.ph/shop-portable-speakers/?spm=a2o4l.home.cate_2_2.2.239e359dxynAFV'
           )

xpath = '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]'
link_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)

links = []
for link_el in link_elements:
    href = link_el.get_attribute("href")
    print (href)
    links.append(href)
driver.quit()
```

The code runs and prints the following:

```
runfile('C:/Users/David/Desktop/Selenium/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/David/Desktop/Selenium')
C:\Users\David\Desktop\Selenium\untitled1.py:4: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
C:\Users\David\Desktop\Selenium\untitled1.py:10: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  link_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
None
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

With selenium4 as the key `executable_pat`h is deprecated you have to use an instance of the `Service()` class along with `ChromeDriverManager().install()` command as discussed below.

Pre-requisites
Ensure that:

Selenium is upgraded to v4.0.0

```
pip3 install -U selenium
```

Webdriver Manager for Python is installed

```
pip3 install webdriver-manager
```

***Selenium v4 compatible Code Block***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Also use

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "xpath")
```

instead of

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Comment: It seems I already had these installed. I thought it was something to do with the error: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_xpath is deprecated. Please use find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath) instead
  link_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath). I tried to use this syntax but it is telling me variables are undefined. Not sure if I've made a mistake here.

Comment: I updated the answer try this again.