# WebdriverManager issue : Chrome Browser not opening with Selenium +Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver-manager

I am trying to open Chrome Browser with Selenium+Python using webdrvermanager.

Selenoim- 4.0.0
webdrivermanager- 3.5.3
python-3.8.10

````
```     def test_selenum(self):
        #driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        #     service=ChromiumService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=.CHROMIUM).install()))
        #driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("https://google.com")
        print('driver Title:', driver.title)
        print('Driver name:', driver.name)
        print('Driver URL:', driver.current_url)```
````

getting error as below when trying

````
```
self = <test_demo.TestDemo object at 0x0000012811A1BBE0>

   

     def test_selenum(self):
            #driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    >       driver=webdriver.``Chrome(executable_path=r'chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

test_demo.py:351: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:69: in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:93: in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:266: in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:357: in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:418: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x0000012811A88280>
response = {'status': 400, 'value': ''}

    def check_response(self, response: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:

```
````

Comment: What's the selenium and chromedriver version?. Also `executable_path` is deprecated please use `Service`

Comment: Selenium- 4.0.0 , webdrivermanager- 3.5.3 , python-3.8.10, , chromedriver-103/104

Comment: In the question header you mentioned about `webdrivermanager- 3.5.3` where as within the question the error stacktrace is about `executable_path`. What is your exact usecase?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and i used Firefox like this:

```
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

https://github.com/btseee/mongolian-bank-exchange-rate/blob/main/rates/bank_rates.py

Comment: we are supposed to use wither Chrome/IE Edge

Comment: Checkout this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/71987644/11863448]